# Tracking long transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to track long or even unending transactions.

I figured that I can intercept a repository call, log some kind of an ID and the SQL, and relog the ID when its done.

I implemented `EmptyInterceptor`, and added 
`beforeTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx)` and
`afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx)`.

If I use intelliJ, on debug I can see the session ID of the transaction (so I know when it started and ended).

However, that property is private final, without a GET (and because its final, its hard to use reflection).

What Can I do? Is there some other method to get the transaction ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can access any property using reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

Here's an example of how to access a final private variable:

https://javahowtodoit.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/how-to-get-and-set-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection/

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.poalim.***.common.config.MyInterceptor can not access a member of class org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl with modifiers "private final"